# \! In Bash Commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is the function of `\!` in a bash command?

For example, I notice that this command below will differ in behavior with `\!`:

`find subdir -lname 'test*' \! -newer somethinghere`

Google searching does not appear to bring up anything specifically related to `\!` except for command line formatting.

Comment: `\!` is used to escape `!` which causes history expansion otherwise

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a backslash before a character escapes it, preventing it from being parsed as syntax. Thus, `\!` is a terser equivalent to `'!'` -- it ensures that `find` is passed `!` as an argument, without the shell interpreting it in any way.

Without either of these, if `[[ $- = *H* ]]` (which is true in an interactive shell and by default), and if `histchars` is unmodified from its default value, `!` triggers history expansion. This is per the bash man page's QUOTING section:

> When the command history expansion facilities are being used (see HISTORY EXPANSION below), the history expansion character, usually `!`, must be quoted to prevent history expansion.

Answer (score 2):

The ! is for **negation**, for instance:

```
find . -readable
```

will return all readable files/directories, whereas

```
find . ! -readable
```

will return all files/directories that can **not** be read (broken link or -r permission)

The **\** char is for escaping.

However, curiously on my computer (Debian/bash) I need to escape the * char but not the ! one. To be more explicit I need to write

```
 find . -name abc\*
```

but

```
 find . -name abc\* ! -readable
 find . -name abc\* \! -readable
```

work and have same effect

Comment: Not that curious. Old-style history expansion isn't always enabled -- personally, one of the first things I do in setting up dotfiles is turn it off. And it's *always* disabled-by-default in noninteractive shells (ie. those running scripts).